# centroids or boundaries of unincorporated communities

Tags: usa, census, population

I have the [Tiger places](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=Places) (dark green), which I believe contains census designated places. I also have the Census Bureau's [Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles - Places (Incorporated Places and Census Designated Places)](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_place.html) (light green). Those two basically overlap just perfectly as shown here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/u8XGhGO.jpg]

When I look at [the same area on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aberdeen,+CA+93526/@36.9319434,-118.0938654,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x80bfb6581ab05edd:0xfb6a99a69acfa9df!8m2!3d36.9778724!4d-118.2534027), [the unincorporated community of Aberdeen, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberdeen,_California) shows up (as well as Blackrock and some others):

[image]

Are there any sources out there for unincorporated communities? When I check the [USPS zipcode lookup I get a zipcode for Aberdeen](https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=1&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=aberdeen&state=CA&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=), and I imagine I can use something like the [Census Bureau's ZIP code spatial data](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html) to get an idea of what communities are in what zipcodes, but that really doesn't give me the actual centroid or boundary of Aberdeen.

Comment: This may be better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Any chance you could move it over there?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question...Is [this](http://tinyurl.com/y8rorxlk) what you want (press _Run_ below the query form)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin , that's exactly what I was looking for! I see the WKT next to it there when I download the csv extract, are there any other columns available? I've never used wikidata before; looks awesome. And if you drop it as an answer I'd love to mark it as the answer.

Comment: [These](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Q2821569) and probably [these](http://dbpedia.org/page/Aberdeen,_California) fields are available. You need to learn SPARQL to retrieve their values. I think, you can ask additional questions here or on SO. In this question, let you write which fields you need, and I'll try to write example query.

Comment: nicely done! @StanislavKralin you should answer this question with your comment and radpin should accept it...as long as it is still correct. Sorry if this seems like I'm lecturing, just trying to get questions answered and cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using [Wikidata SPARQL Endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/):**

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel ?point WHERE {
?a wdt:P31 wd:Q17343829 ;
   wdt:P625 ?point
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

Place this pseudo-comment — `#defaultView:Map` —  anywhere in the query above, if you want to display results on the map.

Not all unincorporated communities has coordinates in Wikidata. If you do not want to exclude these unincorporated communities from results, use `OPTIONAL`:

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel ?point WHERE {
?a wdt:P31 wd:Q17343829 .
OPTIONAL { ?a wdt:P625 ?point }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

These unincorporated communities has no coordinates in Wikidata:

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel WHERE {
?a wdt:P31 wd:Q17343829 .
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?a wdt:P625 ?point }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

You can add missing coordinates yourself (e.g. for [Carolan, Arcansas](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5044649)).

**Using [DBPedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql):**

```
SELECT ?a SAMPLE(str(?aLabel)) AVG(?lat) AVG(?long) WHERE
{
?a dbo:type dbr:Unincorporated_area ;
   rdfs:label ?aLabel ;
   geo:lat  ?lat ;
   geo:long ?long .
FILTER (lang(?aLabel) = "en")
} GROUP BY ?a
```

The number of unincorporated communities in DBPedia is less than in Wikidata. You can add missing communities creating their pages in Wikipedia.